# Retrieve data from database and display in text boxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Ok, not so good in PHP, i have a database (mysql), and a form with many field submitting to the database, i need to call all the values and display them into the text box's accordingly so they can be edited and submitted again. please help

Comment: this is basic core php. something you should read up on and learn about yourself. we're here to help, not be your teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a very simple example that should get you started.

The values are accessible via (most likely) `$_POST['input_name']`.  Without using [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), you can just get the input values like:

```
$input_name = isset($_POST['input_name']) ? $_POST['input_name'] : '';
```

Then later you'll display it in the form like:

```
echo '<input name="input_name" value="'
    . htmlspecialchars($input_name, ENT_QUOTES) . '">';
```

If you want to use P/R/G, which you should do, you need to store the input in the `$_SESSION`.

```
session_start();
//initialize all inputs to the empty string
if (!isset($_SESSION['inputs'])) {
    $_SESSION['inputs'] = array('input_name' => '');
}
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $_SESSION['inputs']['input_name'] = isset($_POST['input_name']) /* etc. */;
}
```

You can then output it in your form via `$_SESSION` instead of `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with php and HTML:

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli(host,user,pass,db_name);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result  = $con-> query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         $value = $row['column'];
         echo "<input type ='text' value ='".$value."'>";
     }

?>
```

Comment: Really?  Your example overwrites `value` each iteration.

Comment: Accidentally put echo out of while loop

Comment: @Ree this answer is vulnerable to XSS because `value` is not properly encoded.